# Parsing C like structured text into dict

Tags: python, parsing

I have config files structured like simplified C syntax, eg:

```
Main { /* some comments */
    VariableName1 = VariableValue1;
    VariableName2 = VariableValue2;

    SubSection {
        VariableName1 = VariableValue1; // inline comment
        VariableName2 = VariableValue2;
    }

    VariableName3 = "StriingValue4";
}
```

Sections may be recursivesly nested.

How can I parse that file into `dict` in a clean and "pythonish" way?

**[EDIT]**

OK, I've found [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) module :) but maybe someone can tell how to do this without it.

**[EDIT2]**

Because of curiosity, I want to know for future how to write that I think simple task by hand.

Comment: How is `VariableValue1` different from `"StringValue4"` ? Is the former also a string?

Comment: Unquoted value should be treated as INT or FLOAT, eventually if it starts with `0x` as a binstring

Comment: Why do you not want to use pyparsing?

Comment: Because of curiosity, pyparsing is a multitasking tool, I want to know for future how to write that I think simple task by hand.

Comment: @canni: don't be fooled by the apparent simplicity of your file format. Doing this properly "by hand" is far more difficult than using an off-the-shelf parser.

Comment: @PauloScardine is correct.  You will be better off using a general-purpose parsing tool.  If you try to do it from scratch your code will likely be fragile and difficult to maintain.  If you want to learn for the future, learn to use pyparsing.  Learning how to use a useful tool is better than learning how to do a one-off task that will not help you for future tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parser like [SimpleParse](http://simpleparse.sourceforge.net/), just feed it the EBNF definition.

Do you have the format documented in some sort of BNF, don't you? If not, you can tell the next genius inventing another config format instead of using json, xml, yaml or xml that he is not authorized to reinvent the wheel unless he can specify the syntax using [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

It may take some time to write a grammar if you are not familiarized with [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), but it pays. It will make your code well documented, rock solid and easier to maintain.

See the python wiki about [Language Parsing](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) for another options.

If you try to pull some stunt using str.split or regular expressions, every other developer to do maintenance of this piece of code will curse you.

UPDATE:

It just occurred to me that if you replace the `SectionName` with `SectionName :`, `;` with `,` and enclose the main section with a pair of curly braces, this format [will likely to be valid json](http://json.org/).

```
"Name"     = JSON Grammar
"Author"   = Arsène von Wyss
"Version"  = 1.0
"About"    = 'Grammar for JSON data, following http://www.json.org/'
! and compliant with http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627

"Start Symbol" = <Json>
"Case Sensitive" = True
"Character Mapping" = 'Unicode'

! ------------------------------------------------- Sets

{Unescaped} = {All Valid} - {&1 .. &19} - ["\]
{Hex} = {Digit} + [ABCDEFabcdef]
{Digit9} = {Digit} - [0]

! ------------------------------------------------- Terminals

Number = '-'?('0'|{Digit9}{Digit}*)('.'{Digit}+)?([Ee][+-]?{Digit}+)?
String = '"'({Unescaped}|'\'(["\/bfnrt]|'u'{Hex}{Hex}{Hex}{Hex}))*'"'

! ------------------------------------------------- Rules

<Json> ::= <Object>
         | <Array>

<Object> ::= '{' '}'
           | '{' <Members> '}'

<Members> ::= <Pair>
            | <Pair> ',' <Members>

<Pair> ::= String ':' <Value>

<Array> ::= '[' ']'
          | '[' <Elements> ']'

<Elements> ::= <Value>
             | <Value> ',' <Elements>

<Value> ::= String
          | Number
          | <Object>
          | <Array>
          | true
          | false
          | null
```

Comment: This config is extremely 'vendor-specific' it is used to generate binaries encoded with something like basic encoding rules (Type-Length-Value) section nesting and key ordering is essential

Comment: Believe me, I've been there. [alisonar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1419272/alinsoar) made most of your homework already, use a general-purpose parsing tool.

Comment: This format seems close enough to json that you can benefit from adapting a json grammar to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse it recursively, using this Backus Naur form, staring from PARSE:

```
PARSE: '{' VARASSIGN VARASSIGN [PARSE [VARASSIGN]] '}'

VARASSIGN : VARIABLENAME '=' '"' STRING '"'

VARIABLENAME: STRING

STRING: [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*
```

Because your structure is easy, you can use a predicative parser LL(1).

Answer (score 1):

1) Write a tokenizer, i.e. a function that will parse the character stream and turn it to a list of Identifiers, OpeningBrace, ClosingBrace, EqualSign and SemiColon; comments and spaces are discarded. Could be done using Regexpr's.

2) Write a simple parser. Skip the first Identifier and OpeningBrace.

The parser expects an Identifier followed by one of EqualSign or OpeningBrace, or a ClosingBrace.

2.1) If EqualSign, must be followed by Identifier and SemiColon.
2.2) If OpeningBrace, invoke the parser recursively.
2.3) If ClosingBrace, return from the recursive call.

In the processing of 2.1, enter the desired data into the dict, the way you like. You could prefix identifiers with the names of the enclosing blocks, e.g.

```
{"Main.SubSection.VariableName1": VariableValue1}
```

Here is prototype code for the parser, to be called after the tokenizer. It scans a string where a **letter** stands for an identifier, separators are **={};** and the last token must be a **$**.

```
def Parse(String, Prefix= "", Nest= 0):
    global Cursor
    if Nest == 0:
        Cursor= 0

    # Scan the input string
    while String[Cursor + 0].isalpha():
        # Identifier, starts an Assignment or a Block (Id |)
        if String[Cursor + 1] == "=":
            # Assignment, lookup (Id= | Id;)
            if String[Cursor + 2].isalpha():
                if String[Cursor + 3] == ";":
                    # Accept the assignment (Id=Id; |)
                    print Nest * " " + Prefix + String[Cursor] + "=" + String[Cursor + 2] + ";"
                    Cursor+= 4

        elif String[Cursor + 1] == "{":
            # Block, lookup (Id{ | )
            print Nest * " " + String[Cursor] + "{"
            Cursor+= 2

            # Recurse
            Parse(String, Prefix + String[Cursor - 2] + "::", Nest + 4)

        else:
            # Unexpected token
            break

    if String[Cursor + 0] == "}":
        # Block complete, (Id{...} |)
        print (Nest - 4) * " " + "}"
        Cursor+= 1
        return

    if Nest == 0 and String[Cursor + 0] == "$":
        # Done
        return

    print "Syntax error at", String[Cursor:], ":("

Parse("C{D=E;X{Y=Z;}F=G;}H=I;A=B;$")
```

When executed, it outputs:

```
C{
    C::D=E;
    X{
        C::X::Y=Z;
    }
    C::F=G;
}
H=I;
A=B;
```

proving that it did detect the nesting. Replace the print statements by whatever processing you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) to write a parser for this format.